# Oracle: result_cache on materialize views

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

is the Oracle *result_cache* option working for *materialized views*? I didn't find it anywhere (explicitly) documented. For me I don't see any performance improvements for materialized views. It works on tables in my test scenario.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Check your execution plan. It should show you whether it uses the result cache or not.

Answer (score 0):

It was my own fault. In the where clause I compared a date value with *sysdate* and *sysdate* changes of course with every execution.